# Error in external user update record in a custom object through site.com

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, controller, site.com

I am trying to have guest users to update a record in a custom object through a site using a custom controller. However I get the error of "List has no rows for assignment to SObject'

This is the old record:
[image]

When an user goes to the site, they input data through site.com, then the record looks like this.
[image]

**Here is my VF page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Resource_Request__c" extensions="ResourceRequestClass">
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/t31.0-8/12308103_999557600066962_8267855404010951614_o.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
    }
</style> 

<apex:messages />
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageblock >
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Criteria">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Request ID: "/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!RequestID}"/>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Name: "/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!RequesterName}"/>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Email: "/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!RequesterEmail}"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!saveRequest}" immediate="true"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" immediate="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Here is my Apex class:**

```
public class ResourceRequestClass{
    public resource_request__c request {get;set;}
    public String requestId {get;set;}
    public String requesterName {get;set;}
    public String requesterEmail {get;set;}

    public ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public ResourceRequestClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void fetchRequest() {
        this.request = [
            select Name, Name__c, Contact_Email__c
            from resource_request__c
            where Name =: this.requestId

        ];
    }   

    public PageReference saveRequest() {
        fetchRequest();

        request.Name__c = this.requesterName;
        request.Contact_Email__c = this.requesterEmail;

        update this.request;

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am unable to update the record.  Any thoughts?  Is there even a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: check access to Resource_Request__c object for guest user profile.Guest user might not have access to Resource_Request__c object

Comment: They do.  It still doesn't work.  The SOQL query returns no result.  The error is "List has no rows for assignment to SObject." The requestid input is not being passed in to my controller.